# How Can we Show Two Iframe With diffrent resources in a single click

Tags: iframe

I am making a plugin of wordpress music player in which when i am adding a song according to every song i am putting a 3 pdf i am fetching data and putting into in a iframe, my problem is that i want to show 2 iframe one for music player and one for pdf, when i click to next song player will change there songs(it is happening)   but pdf i-frame not reflecting according to there data.
Want to show like music player when we click on playlist song song will change also i want same as pdf iframe also change for particular song which i inserted data for this.
Thanks in Advanced 
Any Suggestion or anybody know such type of wordpress plugin in which we can show music player with one other iframe option.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button value="next song" onclick="nextsong()"></button>
     <iframe id="player" src=""></iframe>
    <script>
  function nextsong()
     {
  document.getElementById("player").src= "your song link";}
     </script>
```

Comment: declare all song links in array then change song with click

Comment: i want 2 iframe you suggest me for single iframe for songs.

Comment: use same code for pdf viewer use if and else condition with song name if song name1.text !== pdf name1.txt then iframe1.src="/song1" && iframe2.src="/pdf1" else if -------so on